# MPI Errors in install.packages in R

Tags: r, linux

I try to install my package in R and I get the following error:

> [antonis-dell:20724] mca: base: component_find: unable to open
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_sysv:
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_sysv.so: undefined symbol:
>   opal_show_help (ignored) [antonis-dell:20724] mca: base:
>   component_find: unable to open
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_mmap:
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_mmap.so: undefined symbol:
>   opal_show_help (ignored) [antonis-dell:20724] mca: base:
>   component_find: unable to open
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_posix:
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_shmem_posix.so: undefined symbol:
>   opal_shmem_base_framework (ignored)
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- It looks like opal_init failed for some reason; your parallel process
>   is likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process
>   can fail during opal_init; some of which are due to configuration or
>   environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
>   here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
>   Open MPI developer):
>
> opal_shmem_base_select failed   --> Returned value -1 instead of
>
> ### OPAL_SUCCESS
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process
>   is likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process
>   can fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
>   environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
>   here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
>   Open MPI developer):
>
> opal_init failed   --> Returned value Error (-1) instead of
>
> ### ORTE_SUCCESS
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process
>   is likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process
>   can fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or
>   environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
>   here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
>   Open MPI developer):
>
> ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed   --> Returned "Error" (-1)
>
> ### instead of "Success" (0)
>
> *** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread**
>    on a NULL communicator
>    **MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
>   ***    and potentially your MPI job) [antonis-dell:20724] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully; not able to aggregate error
>   messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were
>   killed! ERROR: loading failed
>   * removing ‘/home/antonis/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/sprint’ Warning message: In
>   install.packages("/home/antonis/Desktop/SPRINT/sprint.tar.gz",  :
>   installation of package ‘/home/antonis/Desktop/SPRINT/sprint.tar.gz’
>   had non-zero exit status

The steps to install my package is:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk -y

sudo apt-get install build-essential -y

sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc -y

sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12 /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1
```

Then to install SPRINT from R:

```
sudo R

> install.packages("rlecuyer")
> install.packages("/home/antonis/Desktop/SPRINT/boot_1.3-7.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
> install.packages("/home/antonis/Desktop/SPRINT/class_7.3-5.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
> install.packages("/home/antonis/Desktop/SPRINT/lattice_0.18-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
> install.packages("e1071")
> install.packages("ff")
> install.packages("randomForest", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
> biocLite("ShortRead")
> biocLite("multtest") 
> install.packages("rPython","http://rforge.net/",type="source")
> library(rPython)
```

Above commands executed without error. But the command

```
> install.packages("/home/antonis/Desktop/SPRINT/sprint.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

gives above error. What I miss here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: R 3.2, Java 7 and an [archived package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sprint). Are you sure there are no modern alternatives for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure there are. But I want to compile a 2 years old code with these. Did you know why I have this error?

Comment: I do not know for sure. One possible problem is that you are installing two different MPI libraries.